# Insert random <script> for using $(document).ready(function()}); in Joomla

Tags: jquery, html, joomla1.5, javascript

I have an article in which I use PHP code inside the text editor in Joomla, in the backend. I can see jQuery already called when the page loads, here is my code inside the Article edit textbox:

```
<?php
$username="XXX";
$password="XXX";
$database="XXX";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM birthdays ORDER BY name")
or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table width='100%' cellspacing='10' cellpadding='0' border='0'>";
echo "<tr valign='top'><th align='left'></th><th align='left'>Name</th><th align='left'>Email</th><th align='left'>Day</th><th align='left'>Month</th></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td valign="top"><a href="#" id="'.$row['id'].'" class="delete_birthday"><img src="administrator/components/com_media/images/remove.png" alt="Delete user" /></a><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$row['id'].'" /></td>';
    echo "<td valign='top' style='border-bottom:1px dotted #333333; padding:2px;'>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td valign='top' style='border-bottom:1px dotted #333333; padding:2px;'>";
    echo $row['email'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' valign='top' style='border-bottom:1px dotted #333333; padding:2px;'>";
    echo $row['birthday'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' valign='top' style='border-bottom:1px dotted #333333; padding:2px;'>";
    echo $row['birthmonth'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hello");
});
</script>
```

At the moment, nothing alerts (just alerting for testing if jQuery gets recognised, I am obviously going to put in `click` handlers), so I assume the `$(document).ready()` never gets triggered. I can see the code in the source, but it just never gets called.

Anybody have any advice? BTW. the SC jQuery plugin is installed already to prevent library conflicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [SC jQuery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/scripts/7230) page, it loads jQuery in "no conflict" mode. This means that the `$` function won't be available, and you need to use `jQuery` instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

[More information](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) on jQuery.noconflict.

Comment: These days I use the above as follows:

`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // still get to use $()
    $('.element').something();
});`